# "First" with no article?

Tags: articles

This is a paragraph from a newspaper:

> An analysis of sleep found that people get more REM sleep in winter.
> If the findings can be replicated (...), this would be **first evidence**
> for a need to adjust sleep habits to seasons.

Why is there no "the" before "first" in this case?

[image: image of the newspaper article]

Answer (score 3):

This usage of "first" as a determiner is indeed nonstandard. I suspect that this is an abbreviated style used to fit the text into a small space; that would also explain the use of "seasons" where "the seasons" would be expected.

Comment: Yes, normally one would expect a 'the' there, and it looks strange to omit it.

Comment: "this would be evidence" is fine (indeterminate mass noun), so I wonder if the writer was thinking of that, then added "first" but didn't bother to add an article. It could be for space or could be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

*first* is being used as an adjective in your example.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/first)
> first, adjective
> preceding all others in time, order, or importance: such as
> *She won first prize;
>
> his first girlfriend;
>
> couldn't get the car out of first gear*

Although uncommon, it is therefore a conventional usage.

There is an element of redundancy in the conventional usage. If something is first, it has the unique attribute of being first, not second, nor last nor any other. That being the case, there is only one first, and as such it is redundant to say *the* first. Nevertheless, the usage is dominant.

Here are a couple of examples of simple adjectival use from online search for “First news of”.

(I can only show screen copy of the search because opening the links leads to restricted access):
[image]